# show more photos

Tags: android

I am getting photos from website and display them in Grid view, but
here I do not want display all of them at time,

1. I want show only 10 photos and a "more" link below the grid , but i
   can display "more" link at top, how can I add it at bottom?
2. when user click on "more" it should display the another 10 photos
   only, I need to refresh the grid, how can we refresh the grid?

Answer (score 1):

To display the "more" button on the bottom you need to define a layout.  The Android [development documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) has a number of examples of layouts that may fit your need.

To update the grid you need to add an onClick listener to your "more" button.  Are you using an Adapter to fill your grid?  The [DataSetObserver](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/database/DataSetObserver.html) is designed to allow you to update the dataset of your grid.